# Restricting re-renders to specific state change in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I have a component with three different states and I only want the component to re-render when one specific state in that component changes, how would I go about doing that?

Below I've included a code example. Say I only want this component to re-render when setSecondState() is called, not when setFirstState() or setThirdState() is called.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
     const [firstState, setFirstState] = React.useState(0);
     const [secondState, setSecondState] = React.useState(false);
     const [thirdState, setThirdState] = React.useState("");

     return (
          <div>
                Rendered
          </div>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put those in state use ref instead. You can update ref value by updating ref.current, it won't cause re-render.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => { 

     const firstRef = React.useRef(0);
     const [secondState, setSecondState] = React.useState(false);
     const secondRef = React.useRef("");

     const someFunction = () => {
         firstRef.current = 10;
         secondRef.current = "foo";
     }

     return (
          <div>
                Rendered
          </div>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle function.
This will return a boolean which tells react to render or not.

In the below example when v1 value changes it does not trigger re-render while changing v2 triggers a re-render.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    v1: 0,
    v2: 0
  }
  
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    console.log('v1: ', nextState.v1, ', v2: ', nextState.v2);
    return this.state.v1 === nextState.v1
  }
  
  render(){
    const { v1, v2 } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState(({ v1 }) => ({ v1: v1 + 1 }))}>{`Increase but do not render: ${v1}`}</button><br />  
        <button onClick={() => this.setState(({ v2 }) => ({ v2: v2 + 1 }))}>{`Increase and render: ${v2}`}</button>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```